# Validation error in XML Schema for complexType

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

**Error:**

> s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'viviendas' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: complextype.

**Schema:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://wwww.vivienda.io"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.vivienda.io">
  <xs:element name="viviendas">
    <xs:complextype>
      <xs:sequence maxoccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="vivienda" minoccurs="1">
          <xs:complextype>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="direccion">
                <xs:complextype>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="calle"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="numero"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="localidad"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="provincia"></xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complextype>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="refCatastral"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="habitaciones">
                <xs:complextype>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="habitacion" minoccurs="1">
                      <xs:complextype>
                        <xs:attribute name="area" use="required" type="xs:string">
                          <xs:complextype>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                              <xs:mininclusive value="1"/>
                              <xs:maxlength value="2"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                          </xs:complextype>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        <xs:attribute name="tipo" use="required" >
                          <xs:complextype>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                              <xs:pattern value="salon|cocina|baño|dormitorio"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                          </xs:complextype>
                        </xs:attribute>
                      </xs:complextype>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complextype>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="servicios">
                <xs:complextype>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="servicio" minoccurs="1"></xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complextype>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complextype>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="comprador" minoccurs="0" maxoccurs="1">
          <xs:complextype>
            <xs:attribute name="dni" use="required">
              <xs:simpletype>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}[A-Z]{1}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpletype>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="nombre"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="edad" >
                <xs:simpletype>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:mininclusive value="1"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpletype>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ref_catastral"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complextype>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complextype>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hi @Salve, welcome to StackOverflow!  I've fixed a few issues in your post this time, but in the future please make sure to do the following: (1) Do not use tags in question titles; (2): try to make your question title give a clear indication of your problem; (3): do not post links to content/code, just post the code directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML tags are CaSe SenSitIve.  `complexType` != `complextype`.  You need to fix that throughout your schema - it's expecting to find `<xs:complexType>` but instead finding `<xs:complextype>`, which is not valid.

It looks like you will have similar problems elsewhere - for example, `simpleType`, `maxLength` are other tags that have different casing than the lower case names you've used in your schema.  As you fix each error,  your validation software should indicate the next error.

Comment: This is correct (+1) but only the first of many issues that must be resolved with OP's XSD.

Comment: I've gone ahead and provided a [complete list of errors and corrections](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30876231/290085) in another answer.

Comment: I was somewhat hoping to foster an attitude of research, but I also probably don't have quite the extent of knowledge you have at your fingertips ;)

Comment: I'm sure you have the knowledge, but, unlike me, you have the wisdom and sufficient self control to resist having to compulsively keep fixing the XSD until it's right.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As Dan Field indicated, you have to take care of case in `complexType` (as well as in all XSD element names).  However, there are many more issues to address in your XSD.  Here is the complete list, followed by a completely corrected XSD:

1. `xs:complextype` -> `xs:complexType`
2. `maxoccurs` -> `maxOccurs`
3. `minoccurs` -> `minOccurs`
4. `xs:attribute` cannot have a `xs:complexType` child.
5. `mininclusive` -> `minInclusive`
6. `maxlength` -> `maxLength` but `maxLength` cannot appear as facet to
   restriction on `xs:integer`; changed to `maxInclusive="99"`.
7. `xs:string` cannot appear on `xs:attribute` along with the
   specification of a local type via `xs:simpleType` too.
8. `xs:simpleType` -> `xs:simpleType`
9. `xs:attribute` must appear *after*, not before, `xs:sequence`.

Here are the above corrections applied to your XSD such that no further errors remain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://wwww.vivienda.io"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.vivienda.io">
  <xs:element name="viviendas">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="vivienda" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="direccion">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="calle"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="numero"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="localidad"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="provincia"></xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="refCatastral"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="habitaciones">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="habitacion" minOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="area" use="required">
                          <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                              <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                              <xs:maxInclusive value="99"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                          </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        <xs:attribute name="tipo" use="required" >
                          <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                              <xs:pattern value="salon|cocina|baño|dormitorio"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                          </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="servicios">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="servicio" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="comprador" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="nombre"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="edad" >
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ref_catastral"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="dni" use="required">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{9}[A-Z]{1}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```